# Definition of Universal enveloping algebra of a lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

I am a physics student, and I am trying to understand the Casimir operator from a formal perspective; therefore, I come to learn what's Universal enveloping algebra.

Two definitions of Universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ of a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ are shown in [Wikipedia page of Universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra#Formal_definition).  The Universal enveloping algebra is defined on the tensor algebra
$$T(\mathfrak{g})=\bigoplus_{k=0}^{\infty} T^k V=K \oplus \mathfrak{g} \oplus(\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}) \oplus(\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}) \oplus \cdots$$
where $K$ is the field over which the Lie algebra is defined. Then, one definition is we can "lift" the lie bracket of the original by lie algebra to the tensor algebra by defining
$$a \otimes b-b \otimes a=[a, b],$$
$$[a \otimes b, c]=a \otimes[b, c]+[a, c] \otimes b,$$
$$ [a, b \otimes c]=[a, b] \otimes c+b \otimes[a, c].$$
Then the universal enveloping algebra $U({\mathfrak {g}})$ of ${\mathfrak {g}}$ is defined as the quotient space
$$U(\mathfrak{g})=T(\mathfrak{g}) / \sim$$
where $T(\mathfrak{g})$ is the  tensor algebra of the lie algebra, and the equivalence relation $\sim$ is given by
$$
a \otimes b-b \otimes a=[a, b].
$$
**My first question is**, Can you explicitly show me some examples of how two elements of the tensor algebra are equivalent under the given equivalent relation? Does this mean the elements like (a,b,...) and (0, a,...,b) are equivalent as they give the same element under the lie bracket? Or something else?

In the Wikipedia page, there is one sentence explain the effect of the quotient:

> The result of this lifting is explicitly a Poisson algebra. It is a unital associative algebra with a Lie bracket that is compatible with the Lie algebra bracket; it is compatible by construction. It is not the smallest such algebra, however; it contains far more elements than needed. One can get something smaller by projecting back down.

**My second question is**, why quotient this equivalent relation can give the smallest such algebra?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yeah, I realized that. I am trying to get an intuitive understanding. A lie algebra is a vector space with a lie bracket defined. I think the tensor algebra here is to introduce multiplication. Then, we define the lie bracket on the whole tensor algebra using the lie bracket of the original lie algebra. I think we almost get the space with both lie bracket and multiplication defined. Then I don't understand why we need to divide the two-side ideal (the second definition shown on the Wikipedia page).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry for that. I found the word form [Equivalence_class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class). Do you mean it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry, I'm really confused because I also found the terminology 
 Equivalence class in [Umich lecture note](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/IdealsAndQuotientRings-ANSWERS.pdf,),[MIT lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-703-modern-algebra-spring-2013/resources/mit18_703s13_pra_l_9/) and [Berkeley lecture notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~apaulin/AbstractAlgebra.pdf). So, it seems the equivalence class is some well-known thing.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am very sorry for my poor description of the problem. I rephrase it, hoping it's better now.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez So those elements map to the same element under the lie bracket that belongs to the equivalent class, is my understanding right?

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness, I lost the word "same". I mean, for example, the lie bracket of $a\in \mathfrak{g}$, $(a,0)\in T^2(\mathfrak{g})$ and $(0, a)\in T^2(\mathfrak{g})$ are same; therefore they belong to the same equivalent class, is this correct?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm sorry to waste your time. I really want to figure it out, and I think I haven't understood it correctly. If two elements are equivalent  $x~y$, I think it means they satisfy some constraints. So, what's the meaning of the lie bracket here defining the equivalent relation, or what's the constraint given by the lie bracket? In your previous example, you said $x \otimes y$ and $y \otimes x$ are different elements in tensor algebra, but that also confused me because if $[x,y]=0$, it means $x=y$ and $x \otimes y$ and $y \otimes x$ are same element I think.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for your suggestion and patience!